# Fill data frame columns with ranges of values

Tags: r

How do I build a data.frame with 30 rows that looks like this?:

```
1  1
1  2
1  3
2  1
2  2
2  3
3  1
...
10 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
data.frame(a = rep(1:10, each = 3), b = 1:3)
```

The b vector is recycled because it is shorter than a.

If you want to avoid recycling you could do:

```
data.frame(a = rep(1:10, each = 3), b = rep(1:3, 10))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `expand.grid` you can create a data frame from all combinations of the supplied vectors:

```
expand.grid(1:3,1:10)
```